# IBM Bluemix issue in uploading nodejs app

Tags: node.js

An instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within health check timeout
exit status: 1, CRASHED

```
The detailed log is - 2015-05-12T16:44:58.69-0700 [API/10]     OUT App instance exited with guid 4887f
db9-8549-4aa1-b803-cb064e2ff407 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"4887fdb9-8549-4aa1-b803-cb064e2ff407", "version"=>"ec5e927e-937e-477d-8b8b-442f
9ff2ec54", "instance"=>"5d1eecbb9cfc46d4af4edba7c731ddf1", "index"=>0, "reason"=
>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections
within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1431474298}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your code is not setup to listen on the Bluemix assigned port. Because of this, Bluemix notices that your app is not accepting connections, and so it stops (crashes) the app.

more details are below:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/22585/pushing-nodejs-app.html

Answer (score 0):

This indicates a problem with your application. It failed to start.

```
cf logs <app name> --recent
```

This command will give you the logs which should help you.